# If we are about to write a minimal ConTeXt primer, what to cover?

Tags: context

I need to write a ConText primer for those who never used ConTeXt, and have no LaTeX background. What should I cover in order to give a precise overview of this system?

Comment: Like "[Context, an excursion](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/mp-cb-en.pdf)"?

Comment: Less than that. I thought something that would generate this very good book, the very basic ideas.

Comment: If you want something as short as possible, you have to ask yourself what these people you are targeting really need to know. Then, start with the excursion and delete everything you do not need...

Comment: This is kind of a subjective question which might easily leads to discussions and is not very suitable for the question & answer scheme of this site. This should better discussed on a ConTeXt forum of mailing-list. Feel free to open a new [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) for this here.

Comment: I understand your point of view, but let me respectfully disagree. I think it's not subjective, because I'm asking for the very "typographic axioms" of ConTeXt, if it exists, the ones with which someone can walk on his own feet. And the strategy of deleting from "Excursion" is a hard one: maybe someone is in the same need I am, and can provide the clues I'm asking for.

Comment: Orbis: I however this that it should be at least a Community Wiki then. Any objections I turn it into one? (Note that up-votes no longer give your reputation then)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Browsing through the "Excursion", I found the top ten commands list:

1. `\starttext`, `stoptext`
2. `\chapter`, `\section`, `\title`, `\subject`, `\setuphead`, `\compl`
3. `\em`, `\bf`, `\cap`
4. `\startitemize`, `\stopitemize`, `\item`, `\head`
5. `\abbreviation`, `\infull`, `\completelistofabbreviations`
6. `\placefigure`, `\externalfigure`, `\useexternalfigures`
7. `\placetable`, `\starttable`, `\stoptable`
8. `\definedescription`, `\defineenumeration`
9. `\index`, `\completeindex`
10. `\setuplayout`, `\setupfootertexts`, `\setupheadertexts`

I think it's a good starting point to a minimal primer.

Comment: Please use back-ticks `\`` to format inline code (or mark the commands and press CTRL+K).

Comment: Have you seen [ConTeXt Macro Top Ten](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/info/context-top-ten/cmds.pdf)

Comment: @Aditya: Perhaps you could make that an answer, so we can remove this question from the 'unanswered' list.

Comment: @Joseph: I was waiting for a reply from Orbis. @ Orbis: If my link answers your question, please add in your reply (and accept your answer).

Comment: @Aditya Thank you. [ConTeXt Macro Top Ten](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/info/context-top-ten/cmds.pdf) is quite what I needed.

Comment: @Orbis: Please add the link to ConTeXt Top Ten in your answer

Answer (score 1):

List of Top Ten ConteXt commands from Hans Hagen's manual "ConTeXt an Excursion" is a starting point, but for me it can never be less than eleven.

`\setuppagenumbering`

is a must.

P.S.

Twelve actually, add to it `\setuppapersize`.

P.P.S.

Also:

1. `\page`
2. `\startlinecorrection`
3. `\setuppagenumber` for ultimate control of page numbering.

Comment: I'd even suggest replace #5 with \setuppagenumbering. What about rewrite that list?

Comment: Perhaps. I, personally, do not use abbreviations at all, mainly because I almost never deal with source files other than in xml format.

Comment: Couple more absolutely indispensable commands: